# Maven outputs multi-module src and test directories from command line

Tags: maven, build

I used to check maven project's src and test directories from command lines below, respectively:

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.build.sourceDirectory
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.build.testSourceDirectory
```

However, when the project has multiple modules, the above output becomes unreliable. I found each of the above commands outputs exactly one directory, and most of the cases that directory does not even exist in that project! When maven actually builds, it knows to find src and tests in the corresponding module directories.

One example project is Apache Jackrabbit: 
    https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit
The above command for src outputs the directory that does not exist in this project, but maven knows what are the actual directories to build.

Here, my question is, does maven support any command line options to output all of the src and test directories, when the project has multiple modules that overwrites the default src/test directories? If yes, what is it?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. In a Maven project `project.build.sourceDirectory` is `src/main/java`. This is defined in the Super POM. The fact that the folder exist or not is irrelevant. I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: However, how do I know the *actual* source directory? Maven must know about it, otherwise it won't compile. The question is to ask what the actual directories are. For example, in the given jackrabbit project in the post, that source dir (from command line output) does not even exist, but it can compile.

Comment: But the actual source directory _is_ `src/main/java` (unless that property was overriden). Maybe it doesn't exist but, as I said, it is irrelevant.

Comment: What do you mean by it is *irrelevant*? I am interested in the actual directories maven use to build. If it does not exist, how can maven build? So there must be one or more directories there, and I'm sure they are the ones overwritten by <modules> in pom.xml. The question asks if maven provide cli to output those dirs.

Comment: Look at it this way. Consider each Maven project and module separately. Each has a separate `project.build.sourceDirectory`. For the parent project that has `pom` packaging, `project.build.sourceDirectory` _is_ `src/main/java` but that directory doesn't exist: no problem: nothing to compile. For the modules, that property points to the `src/main/java` of those modules, that directory exist, so it compiles something. Come to think of it, maybe that's what you're missing to understand: there are as many `project.build.sourceDirectory` as projects and modules.

Comment: Cool. I think that is a great start now. So maybe recursively get all of the src directories by getting into each module and run the above command line will work. Thanks!